# Feasible way to get more people with edit-approval privileges?

Tags: discussion, reputation, edits, suggested-edits, privileges

I'm a relatively new contributor to StackOverflow, and it's something that I rather enjoy.

Right now, I don't have enough rep to start approving edits. I'm wondering if there's a feasible way to get more "new users" trained up or "trusted" to approve edits.

I would like to be able to do that, but of course it's always important to keep the spammers off. SO! Here's an idea.

What if there are a certain subset of edits that are allowed to be users with lower rep (Apprentices), BUT those approvals must be approved by users with higher rep. This way, it gives everyone the chance to start contributing right away, AND it makes sure that the spammers aren't able to just blow through edits that don't make sense.

Maybe once an apprentice has had a certain amount of approved edit-approvals (sorry if that's confusing) then they will be able to approve edits without supervision from users with higher rep?

This would mean initially more approvals to sort through, but in the longer term it would allow for more people to be able to approve edits.

Does anyone think that makes sense or is feasible?

Comment: I felt the same way, originally. I think you improve your judgment and editing intuitions a lot more than you think, just by being active for a large period of time. Just focus on contributions with what reputation privileges you have (edit for clarity)

Comment: We already have too much edits to review.

Comment: Anybody (including anonymous visitors) can suggest an edit and there's a system for reviewing them. Did you have something different in mind?

Comment: @AnnaLear They are asking for the ability to approve edits not just make them.

Comment: @Downvoters, what gives? It was an honest question of whether or not it was feasible...

Comment: @matrixugly - No worries, downvotes work differently on meta sites as opposed to regular sites. Basically, they specify disagreement with the proposal.

Comment: @matrixugly People are voting on the feature request.

Comment: Can I not make it a feature request then, I'm more interested in people's opinions.

Comment: Changed to "Discussion" not "feature-request"

Comment: Well now it's a discussion about a feature request :P

Comment: The "Downvoting on feature requests" behaviour isn't specifically based on a question having the "feature-request" tag, but whether the question is about a feature request, which this question is.

Comment: @matrixugly The fact that you're mis-tagging your feature request by not including the appropriate tag doesn't mean people won't vote on the feature that you are actually requesting in the post body.

Comment: If you're simply looking for ways of "giving back" or contributing to the site, there are lots better things you can do besides approving suggested edits.  Answering questions is of course the obvious one.  Contributing great answers to good questions is about the most helpful thing you can possibly do.  You can of course spend your time editing posts, as real good quality edits can be very valuable, when you turn a poor post into a good one lots of people benefit.  While there are dozens of other things, those two are really head and shoulders above the rest in terms of value per time spent.

Comment: @Servy Yes I would agree. I usually don't have a ton of time to be on SO, but edit-approvals would be a small way to contribute given the amount of time that I (and perhaps a lot of other users) would like to spend.

Comment: @matrixugly Suggesting edits is not too terribly time consuming.  If you look at new posts, I'd say about 75% of them probably should use some editing.  (Note of that remaining, most are because they're too far gone to be able to fix, not because they're actually great posts.)  Maybe avoid posts < 5 minutes old to avoid conflicting with other editors.  Finding content to edit is simply not hard, or time consuming, and most edits aren't going to take more than a few minutes of your time, which is only marginally more time than approving edits would take.

Comment: I still don't understand why more people are down voting this, even after I edited the question for discussion. Now I can't delete it and I'm subject to losing reputation continually.

Comment: Maybe they think it is unfeasible? I personally think it is unclear. You have provided no justification for the implicit assumption that there are an insufficient number of edit reviewers presently.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is not a shortage of approvers for suggested edits.  For almost the past year (since the changes to the review system) the suggested edit queue has been sitting right about empty.  It dips up to ten or so items for a few seconds, or possibly an entire few minutes, every once in a while.  There are simply *way* more reviewers than there needs to be with the content generated, so your end goal of creating more approvers is simply not adding value.

Back in the day (over a year ago, with the old system) there were problems because the edit queue was frequently sitting right near its maximum, and that meant people couldn't suggest edits when it was full (meaning edits just didn't get made, and value was lost).  In response to that, a number of changes were made to help bring in more editors.   They were (too) successful.

In the event that we did have trouble reviewing content there is a *much* easier and more effective way of addressing the issue.  Currently reviewers can make 20 reviews per day.  If there was trouble getting content reviewed quickly, that limit could easily be raised (once upon a time it was 50; it had to be *lowered* because there were too many reviewers fighting over the few edits).

Answer (score 6):

I think it's absolutely wonderful that you already want to become more involved in the site. We need users who actively participate and contribute beyond asking the quick question.

But you've been here for two months and have 125 rep on the main site at the moment. Should you be reviewing already? I'd say not. Reviews do not merely involve simple typos. There is a wide range of different edits and they require an understanding of what is appropriate or not. Something you will pick up over time.

Add to that that we already have our fair share of problems with poor reviews, and I don't think what you propose is a great idea. So how can you prepare yourself to be a good reviewer once you do have the privilege? Edit. Edit content into shape. Each accepted suggested edit, up to a limit, will give you 2 rep. If your edit is accepted, great. If it is rejected, try to understand why that happened. If you do, you'll be a better reviewer for it.